# aggregate values from nested collection of JSON into React table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the next JSON by axios:

```
    {
       id: 1,
       title: "Love and death",
       description: "Book",
       isbnNumber: "20938420948",
       language: "ENG",
       price: 1000,
       action: "",
       coverPhotoURL: "/book.png",
       authors: [{
                   id: 1,
                   lastname: "Legran",
                   firstname: "Migele"
                 },
                 {
                   id: 2,
                   lastname: "Lawrence",
                   firstname: "Steve"
                 }
                ]
     }
```

Then i put it into React table:

```
<tbody>
{this.state.books.length === 0 ?
    <tr align="center">
        <td colSpan="6">{this.state.books.length} List is empty.</td>
    </tr> :
    this.state.books.map((book) => (
        <tr key={book.id}>
            <td>{book.id}</td>
            <td>{book.title}</td>
            <td>{**??? need aggregate value**}</td>
            <td>{book.description}</td>
            <td>{book.language}</td>
            <td>{book.price}</td>
            <td>{book.action}</td>
        </tr>
    ))
}
```

I need to put into author column aggregate values from author collection like this: **Legran Migele, Lawrene Steve**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
{(book.authors || []).map(({firstname, lastname}) => `${lastname} ${firstname}`).join(", ")}.
```

This will give you comma separated names

```
<tbody>
{books.length === 0 ?
    <tr align="center">
        <td colSpan="6">{this.state.books.length} List is empty.</td>
    </tr> :
    books.map((book) => (
        <tr key={book.id}>
            <td>{book.id}</td>
            <td>{book.title}</td>
            <td>{(book.authors || []).map(({firstname, lastname}) => `${lastname} ${firstname}`)}</td>
            <td>{book.description}</td>
            <td>{book.language}</td>
            <td>{book.price}</td>
            <td>{book.action}</td>
        </tr>
    ))
}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do that:

```
(book.authors || []).map(author => author.firstname + ' ' + author.lastname).join(', ')
```